# SQL Linq query with a function call

Tags: linq

I have the following query which works the way it was intended:

```
var model = db.Cases.Join(db.Parcels,
            c => c.CaseKey, p => p.CaseKey,
            (c, p) => new { cases = c, parcels = p })
            .Join(db.TaxYears,
            cp => cp.parcels.ParcelKey, t => t.ParcelKey,
            (cp, t) => new { caseparcels = cp, taxyears = t })
            .Where(q =>
                (
                    q.taxyears.YearStatus.ToLower() != "disc" &&
                    q.taxyears.YearStatus.ToLower() != "dnf" &&
                    q.taxyears.YearStatus.ToLower() != "perm" &&
                    q.taxyears.YearStatus.ToLower() != "dismissed" &&
                    q.taxyears.YearStatus.ToLower() != "w/d")
                  &&
                   (q.caseparcels.cases.CaseStatus.ToLower() != "dnf" &&
                    q.caseparcels.cases.CaseStatus.ToLower() != "sub" &&
                    q.caseparcels.cases.CaseStatus.ToLower() != "stop" &&
                    q.caseparcels.cases.CaseStatus.ToLower() != "closed") &&
                    (q.caseparcels.cases.FileNum >= FromFileNum && q.caseparcels.cases.FileNum <= ToFileNum) &&
                    (q.caseparcels.cases.PrimaryContactId >= iContactCodeFrom && q.caseparcels.cases.PrimaryContactId <= iContactCodeTo) 
                );
```

I have 2 additional tables (CaseStatus and TaxYearStatus).  This is the definition for CaseStatus:

```
CaseStatus
----------
StatusDescription Varchar(50)
Active int
IsConsideredActive int
```

And this is what the data in the table looks like:

```
StatusDescription    Active    IsConsideredActive
-----------------    ------    ------------------
Closed               1         1
DNF                  1         1
Open                 1         0
```

This is the definition of TaxYearStatus

```
TaxYearStatus
-------------
StatusDescription Varchar(50)
Active int
IsConsideredActive int
```

And this is what the data looks like:

```
StatusDescription    Active    IsConsideredActive
-----------------    ------    ------------------
DISC                 1         1
DNF                  1         1
File                 1         0
```

I need to modify the section that interrogates the YearStatus, instead of testing for the 5 specific values (disc, dnf, perm, dismissed, w/d), it will test to see if YearStatus is considered active. And for the section that interrogates the CaseStatus, I need to do the same and test if the CaseStatus is considered active.

I created a function which returns either a 0 or a 1 based on the status being passed to it.  Here is the function:

```
public static int IsConsideredActive(string whichTable, string passedStatus)
{
    int returnValue = 0;
    var db = new TaxCertEntities();
    if (whichTable== "cases")
    {
        var IsActive = db.CaseStatus.Where(x => x.StatusDescription.ToLower() == passedStatus.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
        returnValue = (int)IsActive.IsConsideredOpen;
    } else
    {
        var IsActive = db.TaxYearStatus.Where(x => x.StatusDescription.ToLower() == passedStatus.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
        returnValue = (int)IsActive.IsConsideredOpen;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

And I modified the script to look like this:

```
var model = db.Cases.Join(db.Parcels,
            c => c.CaseKey, p => p.CaseKey,
            (c, p) => new { cases = c, parcels = p })
            .Join(db.TaxYears,
            cp => cp.parcels.ParcelKey, t => t.ParcelKey,
            (cp, t) => new { caseparcels = cp, taxyears = t })
            .Where(q =>
                    (q.caseparcels.cases.FileNum >= FromFileNum && q.caseparcels.cases.FileNum <= ToFileNum) &&
                    (q.caseparcels.cases.PrimaryContactId >= iContactCodeFrom && q.caseparcels.cases.PrimaryContactId <= iContactCodeTo) &&
                    (ActiveStatus.IsConsideredActive("cases", q.caseparcels.cases.CaseStatus) == 0) &&
                    (ActiveStatus.IsConsideredActive("taxyear", q.taxyears.YearStatus) == 0) 
                );
```

But I get this error message:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
> IsConsideredActive(System.String, System.String)'

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Presumably you're using LINQ to Entities, which translates the C# expressions into SQL queries so the database can execute them. You'll either need to convert your C# method into an expression that can be translated into SQL, or you'll need to create a SQL function that [you can invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/calling-functions-in-linq-to-entities-queries) in lieu of calling the C# function.

Comment: LINQ to databases must be able to translate the query from a C# `Expression` tree to a SQL query. You could either add a join to the tables in your query, or use something like [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to create expression variables that will be expanded in your query.